# Magento Resources: adding promotion conditions

Tags: php, magento

I was just wondering if anyone could point me to some resources on- or technical implementations of programatically- adding new shopping cart/catalog promotion conditions. I've spent a fair amount of time digging around in the relevant core Modules but I'm not clear on the scope of the entire problem or best practices for implementing new conditions.

Does anyone know of any free modules that do this whose source code I could take a look at?

Answer (score -1):

If you go to *admin panel-> promotions-> Shopping Cart Price* Rules 
"Add a new rule" and if you have some basic programming knowledge you should be able to get the hang of it.

Comment: I'm sorry,  I will edit the above post,  I am looking for TECHNICAL implementations,  as in,  how to create NEW conditions.  Sorry for the confusion!  Thanks!